# How l call up the create_student function to enter the information about students?

Tags: python

```
import datetime
    Class student:
     def __init__(self,name,age):
       self.name=[]
       self.age=[]
     def creat_student(self,name,age):
       num=2
       for n in range(num):
        i=input("enter name of student")
        self.name.append(i)
        x=int(input("enter age of student"))
        self.age.append(x)
```

#I want to call up the create_student function to enter information about students, If you implement the program, It does not happen, How I run it?

Comment: hi, first of all is your identation falty and second you should use **class** and not **Class**. st = student(), st.create_student(name, age) should work. Good luck :)

Comment: this code tells me you want to create **Class** of students! for example, math class, algebra class and etc. Am I right? Do you want to create a class of students with a specified number of members(students) and a specified name and age?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to create a python `class` that creates classes of students with specified members with their names and ages. so with this assumption, you can do it in this way:
suppose we are going to create a mathematics class. first of all, you can specify the number of the class member students! so in this way, you tell python I want to create a class named `mathematics_class` with 5 members(for example)!

```
class student:
    def __init__(self , num_students):
        self.name=[]
        self.age=[]
        self.num = num_students

mathematics_class = student(5)
```

till now, we created a `mathematics_class` that has 5 students. but who are these students? here we go:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self , num_students):
        self.name=[]
        self.age=[]
        self.num = num_students

    def creat_student(self):
        """
        self refers to mathematics_class! in general, self refers to the instance of class!
        """
        for n in range(self.num):
            i=input("enter name of student")
            self.name.append(i)
            x=int(input("enter age of student"))
            self.age.append(x)

mathematics_class = student(5)

# then you can call up the creat_student() to enter the information about students! 
mathematics_class.creat_student()
```

when you run this code, python starts asking you to enter the name and age of each student one by one as you wish. but it would be great to add a function to print the name and age of each student of `mathematics_class`! here we go:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self , num_students):
        self.name=[]
        self.age=[]
        self.num = num_students

    def creat_student(self):
        """
        self refers to mathematics_class! in general, self refers to the instance of class!
        """
        for n in range(self.num):
            i=input("enter name of student")
            self.name.append(i)
            x=int(input("enter age of student"))
            self.age.append(x)

    def show_class_students(self):
        print(dict(zip(self.name , self.age)))

        
mathematics_class = student(5)

# then you can call up the creat_student() to enter the information about students! 
mathematics_class.creat_student()

# and use show_class_students() to print the mathematics_class members
mathematics_class.show_class_students()
```

for example if you try to enter name and age of each student like this:
amour 25
shayan 25
helen 26
anton 27
carol 23

then output would be:

```
{'amour': 25, 'shayan': 25, 'helen': 26, 'anton': 27, 'carol': 23}
```

Comment: Thank you ,can l have your WhatsApp number to study together please please

Comment: What's the jop of mathematics_class   in this line (mathematics_class.creat_student)

Comment: @amourIT No, you can't. Keep learning, you are doing well in writing object-oriented code. If you are confronted with problems, SO users are always here to help. `mathematics_class` play instance rule in the line! The meaning of that line is: "python, please run `creat_student()` function for a specific instance of `student` class, named `mathematics_class`. After all, please accept my answer by clicking on the tick button if you accepted my answer.

Comment: Is mathematics_class a variable or class you create it?

Comment: @amourIT it's an instance of the `student` class.

Comment: If I call up the create student function like this(student.create_student())is it true

Comment: @amourIT no it's not.